# $C(X,Y)$ metric space and compactness

Tags: general-topology

I have a question regarding the metric set $C(X, Y)= \{ f : X \rightarrow Y \, | \, f \, \text{is continous and bounded}\}$.

Now, suppose that $X$ is totally bounded and $Y$ is compact. If $F \subset C (X,Y) $ is equicontinuous and closed, then it is compact.

I have attempted to use Arzela-Ascoli theorem. Since $F$ is already equicontinuous, then I attempted to prove that if $F$ is uniformly bounded, then it is a compact set since every sequence has a subsequence that is convergent in this metric space.  I am stuck at the point that I try to prove that it is uniformly bounded. In addition, I have a hard time seeing why I need $X$ to be totally bounded and $Y$ to be compact.

The other way that I think might work: since $F$ is closed, all limit points $f_n \in F$, so that $F$ is a complete metric space $\implies$ what is left to prove is that $F$ is totally bounded. I think a good step will be to show that $F$ is uniformly convergent. However, equicontinuous is only related to function continuity. The fact that $F$ is closed shows that all limit points are inside $F$. I am not sure how to interpret $Y$ as compact though.

Comment: If $Y$ is compact, it's a bounded space, so the uniform boundedness of $F$ is immediate.

Comment: Note that you cannot use Arzela-Ascoli directly, as it requires the domain to be compact. That's why $X$ is assumed to be totally bounded; assuming axiom of choice, completion of $X$ is compact. As $X$ is dense it its' completion, and functions are continuous, they can be uniquely continuously extended to the completion. Then we can invoke Arzela-Ascoli to find desired convergent subsequence, and restrict it back to $X$.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś we need the functions to be uniformly continuous to extend them to the completion.